# Can a Ghoul or Revenant Participate in the Vaulderie or be Subject to a Vinculum?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In the V:tM chronicle I'm currently running my players will soon be dealing with a Sabbat pack, which I am nearly done fleshing out in mechanical and plot terms. One outstanding question I have is related to the ghouls that serve them: can the ghouls be subject to a Vinculum?

Obviously mingling the ghoul's blood in during the Vaulderie wouldn't make the pack feel anything towards the ghoul (even if he or she contributed entirely vitae, the bond would be to the vampire it came from, if anything). But can the ghoul feel bonded to the pack in the same manner as the vampires? Or is it up to specific vampires to control them, as domitor to regnant or otherwise?

I'm blending 2ed and V20, but would be happy to see evidence or argumentation from any edition or supplement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never seen a clear cut answer to this question, but there are strong indications that the sabbat would not do that. Vaulderie is viewed as something akin to a sacrament among the Sabbat, and ghouls would not be viewed as worthy. As "Ghouls and Revenants" discusses on p. 49-50, the Sabbat view most ghouls as disposable tools and vampires are seen as vastly above the ghouls. While it does not state it directly, I take it the ghouls would not be admitted to something as important as Vaulderie. This is somewhat reinforced by the absence of discussion on Vaulderie in the section on Blood bonds in Ghouls and Revenants. If there were to be rules about it, you would expect them to be right there or at least mentioned there.

Now, with all that said about the fact it shouldn't happen, I haven't seen any logical reason or direct statement in any of the books I have saying that it wouldn't work. As a storyteller my ruling would be that it should virtually never happen, however should a ghoul acquire the vitae used in Vaulderie in some way (stealing it if they are independent ghoul, or managing to deceive the vampires involved into thinking they are a vampire themselves...) I would rule that Vaulderie would affect them just as it would a vampire. I both think that better fits the metaphysics of the situation and would make for the best story.

Comment: I like this approach. I agree that the Vaulderie should engender the same feelings in a ghoul as in a vampire, but that a ghoul is unlikely to be allowed to participate (both for spiritual reasons and because a pack member as domitor would probably direct the ghoul in ways that support the pack anyhow).

Comment: A revenant could spend his own vitae that he produced.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Maybe. I haven't seen a clear ruling on that, but I would rule against it. A revenant is not a vampire. As a storyteller, I would not want a revenant to be able to establish blood bonds...or create their own ghouls.